# Adding jQuery selector control to phantomJS headless browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to add jQuery selector controls to a phantomJS headless browser for testing purposes.

Is it possible?

To this point we have been overwriting the check to see if the control exists and haven't made any attempts to manipulate values and test onChange events.

The test I am wanting to run is this:

```
//arrange
//OnChange results in values being stored in cookies
$('#TestControl').val(cookieValue).trigger('change');

//act
var result = $.cookie(cookieName);

//assert
expect(result).toBe(cookieValue);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to actually create $('#TestControl')

Comment: Are you using a fixture? check here - https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/#html-fixtures

Comment: Let me look into this and get back to you. Thank you for pointing me towards that resource

Comment: @aarjithn is it possible not to use fixtures? They started adding JS tests right before I started there so it's possible that they were never looked into

Comment: You can use something like this?

    `var TestControl = $('<input id="TestControl"/>');
    $(document.body).append(TestControl);`

Comment: Can't get that to work. Closer than what I've been doing though. Going to come back in an hour or so and try a few other things. Thank you for help @aarjithn

Answer (score 0):

For creating DOM elements in phantomJS/jasmine, you could do the following:

```
var TestControl = $('<input id="TestControl"/>');
$(document.body).append(TestControl);
```

However, it is better to define the markup in html. The **fixture** module of jasmine-jquery allows you to load HTML content to be used by your tests. The overall workflow is as follows:

In myfixture.html file:

```
<div id="my-fixture"><input id="TestControl"/></div>
```

Inside your test:

```
loadFixtures('myfixture.html')
$('#TestControl').val(cookieValue).trigger('change')
expect($('#my-fixture')).to...
```